# Simple encrypting in Python

Tags: python

I want to write a simple encryption application, where I take a file and add 1 to each byte of the file. The idea is to corrupt a file and make it unreadable, but my code doesn't seem to do anything, because the output is exactly the same as the input.

```
filepath = './wayne.txt'
file = open(filepath, mode='rb') #read binary
file_bytes = bytearray(file.read())
print('File bytes:\n', file_bytes)

#Start the encryption
for byte in file_bytes:
    byte += 1

print('File bytes after encryption:\n', file_bytes)
```

Comment: Modifying `byte` doesn’t modify `file_bytes`, if that is what you are expecting.

Comment: @barny Thats exactly what I am expeting. Why doen't it and how would it?

Comment: Because it's the copy of the element. You could run your loop over `range(len(file_bytes))` and refer to each element as `file_bytes[i]`. The actual list would be modified this way.

Comment: @D.Jones Hmm, comming from Java I didn't expect it to be like that. Thanks!

Comment: Durr - palm slaps forehead - Python __is__ different from Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close - instantiate a second bytearray, and then add each modified byte to that. The bytes in the initial bytearray are not modified in place.

```
    filepath = './wayne.txt'
    file = open(filepath, mode='rb') #read binary
    file_bytes = bytearray(file.read())
    print('File bytes:\n', file_bytes)

    #second bytearray
    output_bytes=bytearray()

    #Start the encryption
    for byte in file_bytes:
        byte += 1
        output_bytes.append(byte)
    print('File bytes

    enter code here`er encryption:\n', output_bytes)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in range(0,len(file_bytes)):
    file_bytes[x] = file_bytes[x] + 1
```